# Magento 2: How to solve No such entity with customerId?

Tags: product, customer, magento2.4, admin-panel, no-such-entity-exception

I am trying to get the customer related data in product details page as an API response and its working fine. But when I open the product view page in admin, I am getting the below error. I checked the mentioned customer id from the error in my database but its not there so I assume that it was deleted. Now, I need to resolve this and tried multiple solutions which are provided by Magento experts over stack exchange and other forums. But none of the solutions worked for me.

[image]

Can anyone please give me a suggestion or solution for this issue?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What does that means ? : `I am trying to get the customer related data in product details page as an API response and its working fine` (working fine ?) What is the result you are getting ? Cause i don't get how it can work is the customer got deleted. Also what do you reffer when you speak of an error on the product page ? Cause on a product page there is no call to customer. So this is probably some custom code you are reffering to ? Anyway if the customer got deleted, it's lost, nothing you can do I guess, unless it's recent and you have a backup.

Comment: somewhere it is checking is is customer loggedin wher customer id pass as null, so you should check first those classes whose methods you are using. or you should pass customer id where it is required.

Comment: @Claims It means I am getting api response with customer data in product api without any issues but in product page at admin I am getting an error since there was a customer got deleted.

Comment: @ZahidHussainMagento You're right. I tried all possible ways and added condition where ever I used customer id but no luck.